# How can I extract specific year range in the table?

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
city_temp = pd.read_csv('weather trend/Tokyo_Japan.csv')
city_temp.head()
```

Then I want to extract the specific range of year like between 1900-1950.
so I used this code like below and I got an error saying "name 'year' is not defined"

```
city_temp[year >= 1900 & year <= 1950].avg_temp
```

plus I tried this code and got an valuerror 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
city_temp[city_temp.year >= 1900 & city_temp.year <= 1950]. avg_temp
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please don't post images of code and errors. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65376104/edit) your question please.

Comment: okay thanks. I'll edit this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the variable `year` is not defined. you need to use `city_temp["year"]` instead

You should also wrap each of the conditions inside parentheses like this:

```
city_temp[(city_temp["year"] >= 1900) & (city_temp["year"] <= 1950)]
```

This is because the `&` operator is prioritized over the `>=` and `<=` operators. (just like multiplication comes over addition in mathematics.)

Comment: I got an error. The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Edited answer now :)

Comment: @박인아 Then, please accept this by clicking the check mark

Answer (score 1):

You can also use pandas [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
city_temp[city_temp.year.between(1900, 1950)]
```

Comment: thank you. I'm a novice of Python. It's also useful